# Dart factory constructors with / without keyword `new`, what's the difference?

Tags: dart

I came across the following code example from [flutter_redux](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/blob/master/example/github_search/lib/redux.dart#L18) example code.  Had a hard time to understand why `factory SearchState.initial()` returns with a `new` keyword while `factory SearchState.loading()` and `factory SearchState.error()` don't.

```
class SearchState {
  final SearchResult result;
  final bool hasError;
  final bool isLoading;

  SearchState({
    this.result,
    this.hasError = false,
    this.isLoading = false,
  });

  factory SearchState.initial() =>
      new SearchState(result: SearchResult.noTerm());

  factory SearchState.loading() => SearchState(isLoading: true);

  factory SearchState.error() => SearchState(hasError: true);
}
```

Just found the Dart language tour not very helpful to this case, and the Dart language specification is too obscure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes from the [effective dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new) guide:

> Dart 2 makes the new keyword optional. Even in Dart 1, its meaning was
>   never clear because factory constructors mean a new invocation may
>   still not actually return a new object.
>
> The language still permits new in order to make migration less
>   painful, but consider it deprecated and remove it from your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. In Dart 2, the `new` keyword was made optional. If you don't write anything when calling a constructor, it's implicitly assumed to be `new`.

Most code still uses `new` because it was required in Dart 1, and some people even prefer it, so you will see code both with and without `new`.