# Utility of optional keyword new in Dart 2

Tags: dart

I don’t understand the advantage of *not* use the `new` keyword in **Dart 2**.

Can someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dart factory constructors with / without keyword \`new\`, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805306/dart-factory-constructors-with-without-keyword-new-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage is just shorter code, for people who don't think having the `new` adds anything valuable to their code.